# How can I solve my system of simultaneous polynomial equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the system of equations

```
(y + 1)(a - x^p*y^q) == 0
(y + 1)x^p*y^q - c*y == 0
```

But I am getting the massage

> this system can't be solved by known methods

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yeah, post the code you are using and we will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Introduce a new variable $z=x^py^q$.

```
eqs1 = {(y + 1) (a - z) == 0, (y + 1) z - c == 0}
res1 = Solve[eqs1, {y, z}]
eq2 = (z == x^p y^q /. First[res1])
Solve[eq2, x]
```

The answer is $y=\frac{c-a}{a}$ and $x=\left(a \left(\frac{c-a}{a}\right)^{-q}\right)^{1/p}$.

Comment: I get a different solution: `sys /. {y -> -a/(a - c), x -> (a (-a/(a - c))^-q)^(1/p)} // Simplify[#, {p, q} \[Element] Integers] &`, with `sys` being the OP's system.

Comment: Thank for the answer by yarchik and Mr. Wizard. The second equation in eqs1 should be (y+1)z-c y==0. It is corrected by Michael.